# Python Numpy: Why is an underscore necessary here

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy
n,m=map(int, input().split())
arr=numpy.array([input().strip().split() for _ in range(n)],int)
print (numpy.transpose(arr))
print(arr.flatten())
```

Why should there be an underscore before "in range" in the third line? It would also be useful if someone explained why .strip and .split need to be applied here.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: it isn't necessary, it can be any valid variable name (technically, any valid assignment target)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` is just a variable, it could be named differently, for example `i`. `_` is just a conventional name for unused variables. In this case, you execute `input().strip().split()` `n` times in exactly the same way, without caring which iteration (`i`) it is.

`.split()` splits the input string by spaces, for example:

```
>>> '1 2 3'.split()
['1', '2', '3']
```

`.strip()` trims whitespace at the edges:

```
>>> '  1 2 3 '.strip()
'1 2 3'
```

You can read more about these methods by googling the docs or, even simpler, running `help(str.split)` in an inerpreter

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the underscore [holds the result of the last executed expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers).

In some cases, it is used to replace a variable that will not be used.

In your example, as you just need to loop n number of times without needing to know the value of each iteration, you can use `for _ in range(n)` instead of `for i in range(n)`.

You can find more information about the underscore in Python here: [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

---

As for the `strip` and `split` methods, here is a quick explanation based on the Python documentation.

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip): Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.
[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split): Return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string.

So from your example, your code takes the input of the user, removes any leading and trailing characters with `strip`, and `split` the input into a list of words.

For example, if the user input is  `Hello World!`   , the result will be: `["Hello", "World!"]`

Hope that helps!